# arm memcpy from mmapped buffer is taking more time compared to memcpy from local buffer

Tags: arm, memcpy

Memcpy from mmapped buffer to local buffer on arm (buffer size:720*576*2) is taking 56ms, where as memcpy from local to local buffer (buffer size:720*576*2) is taking 4ms after applying neon optimizations .

please kindly suggest if is thier any way to reduce memcpy time on mmapped buffer.

mmapped buffer is filled using DMA (arm dm8148 platform).

Comment: That looks suspiciously framebuffer-sized - are you by any chance directly mmap'ing a kernel DMA buffer?

Comment: also if you are just using malloc'ed area without writing anything on it may be you are benchmarking on zero page and getting full cache. anyway 56ms is hell slow. even 4ms is hell slow. you should tell more about platform.

Comment: If the `mmap` buffer is a completely different memory region, it may indeed be that much slower than the SDRAM in your system.  You question is like 'My Ethernet runs fast.  Please make my uart run fast', if this is the case.  You can `mmap` your own local buffer and see if it has the same effect.  If it does, it would be beneficial to tell people?